# Syntax error while declaring a cursor in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, azure-synapse

I am getting a syntax error while trying to run below code to declare a cursor that runs through and print top 10 orders in my `OrderTable`.

> Parse error at line: 3, column: 11: Incorrect syntax near 'OrderCursor'.

Could you help me figure out what am I missing here? Or could this be something related to my database version, which is: Microsoft Azure SQL Data Warehouse - 10.0.9999.0 n?

Thanks for your help

```
DECLARE @Order VARCHAR(11) 
DECLARE @Variant INT

DECLARE OrderCursor CURSOR FOR 
     SELECT TOP 10 ORDER_ID, Variant 
     FROM OrderTable

OPEN OrderCursor

FETCH NEXT FROM OrderCursor INTO @Order, @Variant

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Order no:' + @Order + @Variant

    FETCH NEXT FROM OrderCursor INTO @Order, @Variant
END

CLOSE OrderCursor
DEALLOCATE OrderCursor
```

Comment: [I can't reproduce this error.](https://rextester.com/HLYX16470) the code you've posted is fine.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Right, comment deleted

Comment: Considering all you're doing is printing the top 10 values, I do not think a cursor is necessary.

Answer (score 3):

Azure SQL Data Warehouse doesn't support [cursors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-cursor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#examples). See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-develop-loops) for tips on how to replace them with loops. Hopefully redundant, but just to quote the first meaningful paragraph from the link:

> However, before diving in head first you should ask yourself the
>   following question: "Could this cursor be rewritten to use set-based operations?." In many
>   cases, the answer is yes and is often the best approach. A set-based
>   operation often performs faster than an iterative, row by row
>   approach.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Azure SQL Data Warehouse does not support cursors. It says so right on the top part of the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-cursor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#examples):

> DECLARE CURSOR (Transact-SQL)
>   APPLIES TO: **V** SQL Server (starting with 2008) **V** Azure SQL Database **X** Azure SQL Data Warehouse **X** Parallel Data Warehouse

That being said, A cursor is usually something you want to avoid anyway in SQL.
In fact,  after about 20 years of software development I can probably count on one hand the number of times I've used cursors, and on three fingers the number of times it was justified.

If you could create a question that will show the actual problem you are dealing with (I'm guessing it's not actually attempting to print), I'm sure someone here will be able to help you get a set based solution instead of using a cursor.